# open iOS iPad simulator with React Native

Tags: ios, ipad, react-native

When testing a React Native app with `react-native run-ios` it opens an iPhone simulator.

You can change the virtual device to an iPad in the Simulator options, but the React Native app does not appear in the list of installed apps.

Is there a way to open an iPad simulator from the CLI?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

`--simulator` flag is what you are looking for

For example `react-native run-ios --simulator 'iPad 2'` will run the app on iPad 2 simulator.

As a side node, if you need to get list of available simulators with their names use `xcrun simctl list devices`

Comment: How do you specify iOS version in this command if e.g. you have iPad 2 iOS 8.4 and iPad 2 iOS 9.3?

Comment: `xcrun simctl list devices` shows **iPad Pro** in devices but `react-native run-ios --simulator "iPad Pro"` is showing error: `Could not find iPad Pro simulator`?? Why?

Comment: Hey @Jayraj I hope you resolved this already but I came across the same issue. Solution: `--simulator="iPad Pro (12.9-inch)"`

Comment: I think the commands have changed, before it worked to just write 'iPad Air', but now you need to write 'iPad Air (4th generation)' insteed. I had a bunch of scripts in the old format!

Answer (score 19):

Get device list with this command

```
xcrun simctl list devices
```

Console

```
== Devices ==
-- iOS 13.5 --
    iPhone 6s (9981E5A5-48A8-4B48-B203-1C6E73243E83) (Shutdown) 
    iPhone 8 (FC540A6C-F374-4113-9E71-1291790C8C4C) (Shutting Down) 
    iPhone 8 Plus (CAC37462-D873-4EBB-9D71-7C6D0C915C12) (Shutdown) 
    iPhone 11 (347EFE28-9B41-4C1A-A4C3-D99B49300D8B) (Shutting Down) 
    iPhone 11 Pro (5AE964DC-201C-48C9-BFB5-4506E3A0018F) (Shutdown) 
    iPhone 11 Pro Max (48EE985A-39A6-426C-88A4-AA1E4AFA0133) (Shutdown) 
    iPhone SE (2nd generation) (48B78183-AFD7-4832-A80E-AF70844222BA) (Shutdown) 
    iPad Pro (9.7-inch) (2DEF27C4-6A18-4477-AC7F-FB31CCCB3960) (Shutdown) 
    iPad (7th generation) (36A4AF6B-1232-4BCB-B74F-226E025225E4) (Shutdown) 
    iPad Pro (11-inch) (2nd generation) (79391BD7-0E55-44C8-B1F9-AF92A1D57274) (Shutdown) 
    iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (4th generation) (ED90A31F-6B20-4A6B-9EE9-CF22C01E8793) (Shutdown) 
    iPad Air (3rd generation) (41AD1CF7-CB0D-4F18-AB1E-6F8B6261AD33) (Shutdown) 
-- tvOS 13.4 --
    Apple TV 4K (51925935-97F4-4242-902F-041F34A66B82) (Shutdown) 
-- watchOS 6.2 --
    Apple Watch Series 5 - 40mm (7C50F2E9-A52B-4E0D-8B81-A811FE995502) (Shutdown) 
    Apple Watch Series 5 - 44mm (F7D8C256-DC9F-4FDC-8E65-63275C222B87) (Shutdown)
```

Select Simulator string without ID here is example.

**iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (4th generation)**

Final command

> iPhone

• iPhone 6s

```
react-native run-ios --simulator="iPhone 6s"
```

• iPhone 8

```
react-native run-ios --simulator="iPhone 8"
```

• iPhone 8 Plus

```
react-native run-ios --simulator="iPhone 8 Plus"
```

• iPhone SE (2nd generation)

```
react-native run-ios --simulator="iPhone SE (2nd generation)"
```

> iPad

• iPad Pro (12.9-inch) 4th generation

```
react-native run-ios --simulator="iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (4th generation)"
```

• iPad Air (3rd generation)

```
react-native run-ios --simulator="iPad Air (3rd generation)"
```

• iPad (7th generation)

```
react-native run-ios --simulator="iPad (7th generation)"
```